# C++ Debug assertion failed. vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, function, class, loops, vector

I have been looking around for a solution and I seem to be fixing everything that was wrong with theirs, however mine still doesn't work.

The following code is displaying vectors from a class called Creature, sorting the vectors and then displaying the sorted vectors.

```
    // displaying the unsorted vector
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO_CREATURES; i++)
{
    if (creatures[i].getAlive() != 0) // checking to see if a creature exists
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < creatures[i].getAvaFood().size(); j++)
        {
            cout << creatures[i].getAvaFood()[j] << " ";
        }
    }
}

//sorting the vector
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO_CREATURES; i++) 
{
    if (creatures[i].getAlive() != 0) // checking to see if a creature exists
    {
        creatures[i].bubbleSort(creatures[i].getAvaFood()); // calling a sorting function from creatures[i] passing in the relevant vector (its own.. wait what?)
    }
}

cout << endl;

// displaying the sorted vector
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO_CREATURES; i++)
{
    if (creatures[i].getAlive() != 0) // checking to see if a creature exists
    {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < creatures[i].getAvaFood().size(); x++)
        {
            cout << creatures[i].getAvaFood()[x] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

When I click retry on the error window visual basic takes me to this line in the creature class. Specifically the IF statement.

```
void Creature::bubbleSort(vector<int> &v)
{
    bool swapped = true;
    int temp;
    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            if (v[i] > v[i + 1])
            {
                temp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[i + 1];
                v[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `v[i+1]` is invalid when `i == v.size() - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > v[i + 1])
```

The `for` allows `i` to be all values [0, v.size) which means you will test v[v.size] which is invalid.

Change your for loop to

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
```

You will need to add a check that v.size() is not zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! The program now run, however like you said I do have to check that v.size() is not zero. However, when v.size() is not zero for all the vectors the program should run and it should sort in ascending using the bubble sort function. This is not the case, the vectors don't get sorted and I am again at a loss :S Any ideas?